# Is this normal CPU/Memory usage for a system that runs nothing but Ubuntu as they start up?

Tags: 13.04, performance, system-monitor

Is this the expected CPU/Memory usage for a pure `13.04` 64bit system? I run nothing more than Ubuntu as they are at the moment of the screenshot.

[image: system monitor]

`ps faux`  output: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/zXszetkF)

Comment: It should be less, please post the output of `ps faux` to pastebin.

Comment: Added at the bottom of the question.

Comment: This is about the same as my laptop. except i tend to have one cpu run at around 10 with the rest doing next to nothing, then switch to another, and so on.

Comment: Should I worry about it or it's okay?

Comment: Funny, it looks that the gnome-system-monitor is making the trouble. :D Don't worry. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the relevant lines of your paste, where %CPU is not 0.0. These are all normal processes that would be active during a typical user login session. It does not look like you have anything to worry about.

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      1187  8.7  0.4 196172 38552 tty7     Ss+  14:07   6:31  \_ /usr/bin/X :0 -core -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch -background none
deus      1995  4.6  1.2 1480928 96744 ?       Sl   14:08   3:25          \_ compiz
deus     30695  1.5  0.2 607076 19668 ?        Sl   15:21   0:00          |       \_ gnome-terminal
deus     30702  0.1  0.0  26168  3200 pts/0    Ss   15:21   0:00          |           \_ bash
deus      2015  0.1  0.5 1020772 45468 ?       Sl   14:08   0:05          \_ nautilus -n
deus      2426  0.1  0.1 517176 14152 ?        Sl   14:09   0:06          \_ update-notifier
deus      1972  2.2  0.0 365604  6776 ?        S<l  14:08   1:41 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
deus     30029  5.3  0.3 553456 30216 ?        Sl   14:59   1:12 gnome-system-monitor
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple. The system monitor itself uses the CPU to draw everything out.
If you use `top`,  `htop` for example, you can see that there is no load at all in idle.
(Maybe Compiz will use up some really-really little to draw the current window as well, but it will use far less than the Gnome System Monitor.)

And of course there are things that run periodically. Like apt-get checks for updates and such.

(Now I read the comments, someone already mentioned this. I seen the same problem on earlier Ubuntu versions when I opened it up and the CPU usage went up with it.)